# Tiny MCE4 ignores width

Tags: tinymce-4

I replaced a tinymce 3 with tinymce 4. Tinymce 4 takes all the width available :

```
   tinyMCE.init({ mode: 'textareas',
    theme: 'modern',
    width:"808",
    height : "480"

    });
```

It ignores the width settings. I use it on a rails admin plugin where i cannot change the surrounding HTML. WHat has change in tinymce 4 that can explain this behavior?

i found that : http://fiddle.tinymce.com/jvdaab/1 i cannot reduce width, if someone can it would be great.

Answer (score 3):

You have to remove the quotes :

```
width: 300,
height : 480
```

like this : http://fiddle.tinymce.com/Nzdaab

**Wrong** :

```
width: "100",
height : "480"
```

Answer (score 0):

As "Sébastien Gicquel" said, it must be a Number as mentioned in [TinyMCE 4 docs](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/editor-appearance/#width).

For anyone struggling with the percentage width, I'm not sure if there is an official way to fix this, but you can fix it by adding this CSS:

```
.mce-tinymce.mce-container.mce-panel {
    width: 100%;
}
```